# Jquery use php var and pause

Tags: php, jquery, delay

My php page has at the top of the page before any jquery a php variable called `$pause`.
The value assigned to this is read from a database.

What I'm trying to do using jquery is show a div, then delay for the $pause value then hide the div.

This shows and hides the div, how do I add the delay ?

```
$("#div1").show();
$("#div1").hide();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can parse php inside of your js, you can `echo` it:

```
var pause = <?php echo $pause; ?>
```

If not, attach the value to an element such as a hidden `input` so that you can access the value with jquery.

Then you could do:

```
$('#div1').show().delay(pause).hide(0);
```

Note: You need to pass the `duration` to `hide()` in order for `delay()` to work:

> When a duration, a plain object, or a "complete" function is provided, .hide() becomes an animation method

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2EJ8/3/)

Comment: Slight issue. `$('#div1').show().delay(pause).hide(0); $("#div2").show();` This shows div1 for the correct duration, but div2 shows straight away. How do I show that after div1 ?

Comment: Sorted.. `$('#div1').show().delay(pause).hide(0); $('#div2').hide().delay(pause).show(0);`

Comment: If you set the state of one of the `div's` to hidden you can call `toggle()` on both at the same time, [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/b2EJ8/5/)

Answer (score 2):

add $pause to a HTML Element...for example body:

```
<body data-pause="<?=$pause?>" >

</body>
```

and js:

```
$("#div1").show();

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#div1").hide();
}, parseInt($('body').attr('data-pause'), 10));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to keep your javascript Inline write this at the end of your html before

```
<script>
$("#div1").show(0).delay(<?php echo $pause; ?>).hide(0);
</script>
```

if you don't want to keep your code inline you can add an attribute to your element and use that:

For example:

```
<div id="div1" delaytime="<?php echo $pause; ?>">Hello World</div>
```

And finally use the javascript below:

```
$("#div1").show(0).delay(jQuery(this).attr('data-pause')).hide(0);
```